# Impossible to delete the last column in a ListView?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having a bit of a trouble here. It seems I can't remove all the columns or (reset) a listview. Here is the relevant code:

```
HWND resultListView = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_RESULTCONTROL);
SendMessage(resultListView, LVM_DELETEALLITEMS, 0, 0); //All items are deleted

//Get numebr of columns
HWND hWndHdr = (HWND)::SendMessage(resultListView, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
int count = (int)::SendMessage(hWndHdr, HDM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0L);

for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < count; colIndex++) {
    ListView_DeleteColumn(resultListView, colIndex);
}

///... Irrelevant code

HWND listbox = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_SELECTEDLISTBOX);
int numberOfItemsSelected = SendMessage(listbox, LB_GETLISTBOXINFO, 0, 0);
vector<string> selectedItemsStringsVector;
char buf[250];
LVCOLUMN buffer;

//Add Selected Columns
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsSelected; i++) { //In this case always 2 "Date" and "Time" for testing.
    SendMessage(listbox, LB_GETTEXT, i, (LPARAM)buf);
    selectedItemsStringsVector.push_back(buf);
    buffer.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT;
    buffer.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    buffer.cx = 100;
    buffer.pszText = buf;
    buffer.cchTextMax = lstrlen(buf);
    buffer.iSubItem = i;
    buffer.iImage = 0;
    buffer.iOrder = 0;
    ListView_InsertColumn(resultListView, i, &buffer); //Works fine. Maybe I add an extra column here?? 
}
```

In debug mode, all my variables have the expected values.

`FirstButtonClick` column count in debug mode (variable count = 2) all good.

[image]

`SecondButtonClick` Column count = 3. But it does not delete them?

[image]

English is not my main language and I am kind of stumped right now...

Comment: You need to delete them in the opposite order, or just always index zero. Once you've removed index #0 out of three columns then index #2 has become #1 and is no longer there to be dropped at the end of the for loop.

Comment: think you take in account that after every `ListView_DeleteColumn` Colum indexes is changed - decrement on 1. so   you need delete every time #0 colum

Comment: Oh! ill try it right away!

Comment: That's it. I just replaced colindex with 0 in the for loop and it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indices of columns in a [header control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775239.aspx) are always consecutively numbered, starting at 0. User code does not control the index of a column. When deleting a column, the indices of columns towards higher indices are shifted down by 1. This is the reason, why the call to `ListView_DeleteColumn` eventually fails.

There are two options to solve this:

- Delete columns starting at the final index down to 0. Deleting the last column does not change the index of other columns, so they stable throughout the deletion operation.
- Always delete the first column (at index 0).

The second option is both easier to implement as well as read. The following loop will delete all columns:

```
for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < count; ++colIndex) {
    ListView_DeleteColumn(resultListView, 0);
}
```